# Jquery Templates: One parent container, many children?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

Using jquery templates, I want to create a list.  I want one parent `<ul />` element with many `<li />` elements, resulting in:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

My data is similar to this:

```
var data =
[
  { val: 'One' },
  { val: 'Two' }
]
```

Currently, the child `<li />` template looks like this:

```
<script id="child-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
      ${val}
    </li>
</script>
```

To get the result I want, I'm currently doing this:

```
$('<ul></ul>').append($("#answer-tmpl").tmpl(data));
```

But this only half-embraces the spirit of Jquery Templates.  I don't want to do any string version of my markup (as above).

Rather, does anyone have an idea on what the parent `<ul />` Jquery Template might look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of giving `tmpl` an array, give it an object which has the array as a field:

```
$("#answer-tmpl").tmpl({ data: data });
```

Then you can modify your template like this:

```
<script id="answer-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <ul>
    {{each data}}
    <li>
      ${val}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/YNm3n/

Comment: My original example was a little broken; you can't have a space between the `{{` and `each`, and the ending `each` needs a `/` before it.

Comment: Fantastic.  It took me a min to see it, but this is a great, simple solution that keeps my original incoming data format in tact.

Answer (score 2):

jt - there's a fantastic example of this at dave wards encosia that will allow you to leverage nice compact composition on jquery templates. take a mosey over to:

http://encosia.com/2010/12/02/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/

I think it'll get you onto the path of convention over configuration on this type of thing, it did me.

Comment: Jim, these are great articles.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var list = $('<ul/>');
$.each(data, function(idx, val) {
    $('<li/>').html(val).appendTo(list);
});
$('body').append(list);
```

This does the job without any string representations. However, the code in your question is **much more efficient** as there is no need for a DOM manipulation for every item.

Reading http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly about the performance issue with DOM insertions is a good idea.

Edit: Looking at the other answer now it seems I've misread the question. I'll leave this answer here anyway so people see that way including the comment why it's bad.

Comment: thiefmaster - i applaud your candour. so much so, +1 for not immediately deleting!! :-)